# Python - Add custom user models in Django admin not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.2) in which I have implemented my models for multiple user types with custom `user` model as the base model. Everything working fine except the admin side, I have register these modles to admin but when I try to add an object from admin interface it's giving an error.

Here's what I have tried so far:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=USER_TYPE, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CHOICES, blank=False)
    contenst = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)


class PersonalBelow18(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    dob = models.DateField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)
    reference_identities = models.ForeignKey(Identities, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='refs')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email+'\'s account with ' + str(self.customer_id)


class PersonalAbove18(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    reference_identities = models.ForeignKey(Identities, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_no = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, help_text='Phone number must be entered in the'
                                                        'format: \'+999999999\'. Up to 15 digits allowed.')

    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email+'\'s account with ' + str(self.customer_id)


class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    contact_no = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, help_text='Phone number must be entered in the'
                                                        'format: \'+999999999\'. Up to 15 digits allowed.')
    collection_use_personal_data = models.BooleanField(blank=False)


class GroupContactPerson(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    customer_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False)
    contact_no = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, help_text='Phone number must be entered in the'
                                                        'format: \'+999999999\'. Up to 15 digits allowed.')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

and here's how I register these models to admin:

**From `admin.py`:**

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'title', 'user_type',
                           'gender', 'contenst', 'last_login')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active', 
            'is_staff', 
            'is_superuser',
            'groups', 
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('email', 'title', 'is_staff', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(PersonalBelow18)
admin.site.register(PersonalAbove18)
admin.site.register(Parent)
admin.site.register(GroupContactPerson)
```

The `Parent` and `GroupContactPerson` models are working well on admin side but the when I try to add an object for `PersonalBelow18` & `PersonalAbove18` models, it gives the following error as:

> TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type int)

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: Also, is the Identity model __str__ method declared? If there any mistake in it, it can be the reason of the error due to the FK displayed in PersonalBelow18 admin interface.

Comment: @IgorBelkov I have added the `__str__` method to all models above.

Comment: @Abdul Rehman as I can see in the answer the problem was in Identity model, as I mentioned ^_^  It's typical for Django in case of this error, so you always need to check not only the models in the app, but also all the connections. Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I debug this problem in these models:

1. I start removing all fields one-by-one
2. Remove a field from `model` & `form` and perform migrations
3. Then test the admin

Then I found that when I removed the `reference_identities` field it start working, so I get that this model was returning an integer, so I fixed that model and it fix the issue.

In short, it's a good approach to find a path to the actual place of problem by removing fields one-by-one and test the admin.